# File Attributes in Powershell when the file is Hidden

Tags: powershell, attributes, hidden

```
$writetime = Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\$searchpath\$searchfile" | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}
```

Using the code above, I attempt to get the LastWriteTime of a file, but if the file is hidden:

[image]

Then it fails to return the LastWriteTime. Is there any way to force it to get what I want regardless of its hidden state on the system?

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Force \\server\path\to\files`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-Force` parameter on `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\$searchpath\$searchfile" -Force
```

Comment: ...said the jedi.